# Fix NighwatchJS Angular output wrapping incorrectly

Tags: angular, testing, e2e-testing, nightwatch.js

I've installed Angular with `ng new` with all defaults, and then used `ng e2e` to scaffold NightwatchJS with all defaults. The tests run just fine now, but the output is unreadable on my Windows shells because *everything* seems to be on one line.

Example output on a small Powershell terminal:

[image: small terminal window, wrapping text]

Or a somewhat wider terminal:

[image: medium size terminal also wrapping text]

Extremely wide terminals (>2000px) still exhibit this wrapping behavior.

I can understand what the intended output is because if I set the width of my terminal exactly right it renders like this:

[image: shell output with nice rendering]

All of this happens for me on Windows 10, on both `cmd` and `powershell` shells, either vanilla or running in the conemu console emulator. It also happens on the "Git Bash" (MINGW64) shell.

How can I fix this line endings issue and get properly formatted output in my shell?

Comment: This is an issue with `boxen` that is used. The team are trying to find a way to get this fixed

Comment: Thx for the info! @AutomatedTester Any chance you have a link to the issue or PR or some other thread for the relevant package? It would be nice to track that as well.